# How do I see output from a Minecraft server terminal when running a bash script?

Tags: bash, minecraft

When I run this command in the directory my minecraft server (fabric modded) is in, I can see my output.

`java -Xmx6G -Xms1024M -jar fabric-server-launch.jar nogui`
[Screenshot of Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO3Y7.png)

However, when I run my bash script in the same directory, even though I can still input regular server commands and have them affect the game, I can't read anything.

`#!/usr/bin/bash`

`$(java -Xmx6G -Xms1024M -jar fabric-server-launch.jar nogui)`
[Screenshot of Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOsfe.png)

Is there any way I could alter my script so that it may display server messages?

Comment: The purpose of [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) is to capture the output of a command and return it. Since the minecraft server does not end, the capturing of its output does not either. To fix your problem, simply remove `$(` and `)` from the script.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the explanation and resource.